# Is there a way to store a pointer to a property in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

For example, if I wanted to do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Property<AddressInfo>>
        {
            { "f", (thing) => thing.Foo },
            { "o", (thing) => thing.Foo },
            { "o", (thing) => thing.Foo },
            { "b", (thing) => thing.Bar },
            { "a", (thing) => thing.Bar },
            { "r", (thing) => thing.Bar },
        };
    }
}

class Thing
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise I have to store both the getter and the setter as a Func and an Action separately.

Comment: There may be a better way to do this if you explained what you will be using this for.

Comment: I second the comment from Dour High Arch.   I can see possible reasons why you would do this, but it seems a bit messy and there is probably a cleaner way to solve the problem. Could you offer more details/context about the problem you're trying to solve with the code?  What does the code do in general?

Comment: Thanks for the replies @JamesHoux & DourHighArch. I do seem to be running into this kind of problem a lot. Basically, when working with a simple class comprised only of Properties, I often want to perform the same action on each of the properties... or associate the properties with certain input commands. It really feels like there should be a way to do this kind of thing without reflection. Perhaps there is some sort of attribute I could use to achieve this? Appreciate that is not the best explanation! But hope you can understand the gist.

Comment: Are you often accessing the properties directly?  I.e. do you have other code calling "thing.Bar" and "thing.Foo" directly more than once?

I feel like we could use more details. IMHO: the fact that you're doing this rather commonly means either a) you've working in a specific area that has a recurring problem not many other people are running into a lot or b) there is a better pattern to use and we need to help get you there.

Comment: If you really need the described behavior, it could be done more elegantly with custom attributes.  You can assign attributes to either an entire class or properties that will collect the properties together at runtime and perform your action on them.  The code is hairy if you're not accustomed to working with reflection.  But once the code is written, the attributes make it stupid easy to work with, super readable, and pretty fast to write and edit. You can reuse it over and over.

But I still am interested in what your consumer code is doing and why you're needing this pattern often.

Comment: One more comment:  I asked whether your consumer code is calling "thing.Bar" and "thing.Foo" often, because if not, then it doesn't even make sense to use properties.  Instead you could just be using a straight dictionary and accessing its elements directly.

Comment: Hi @JamesHoux thanks for your thoughts and interest. Still been thinking about this, and have tried to re-frame the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098960/relating-strings-to-properties-in-c-sharp in case you were interested.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any native way to do it but you can create a struct which would do it.
Disclaimer: I did implement it because it was fun to do. I didn't test so it's just togive an idea and I doubt it's efficient.

```
public class PropertyHolder<T, Y>
{
    private static object[] emptyArray = new object[0];

    public PropertyHolder(Y instance, string propertyName)
    {
        var property = typeof(Y).GetProperty(propertyName);
        var setMethod = property.SetMethod;
        var getMethod = property.GetMethod;
        Set = (t) => setMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[]{t});
        Get = () => (T) getMethod.Invoke(instance, emptyArray);
    }

    public Action<T> Set { get; private set; }        
    public Func<T> Get { get; private set; }        
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
public class Toto
{
    public int TheInt { get; set; }
}

var x = new Toto();
var propPointer = new PropertyHolder<int,Toto>(x, nameof(Toto.TheInt));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Reflection is definitely an option, but it seems a bit inelegant to me, to have to use `nameof()` to convert the property name into a string, and then use reflection to convert that string back to the property name. That is kind of exactly what I want to avoid having to do (though appreciate I didn't mention that in my question :))

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to store a pointer to a property in C#?

No, basically.

You can get pretty close if it is `ref`-return property, but you can't store a `ref` either - you can only use it on the stack.