# Relating strings to Properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties

Say I have a class:

```
class Thing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a sort of URL parameter style convention, where I want to allow the specification of values for this class in the following string format:

```
"{Id}~foo={foo}~bar={bar}"
```

I might want to write a class that does something like this:

```
class ThingHandler
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, (Func<Thing, string> GetValue, Action<Thing, string> SetValue)> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, (Func<Thing, string> GetValue, Action<Thing, string> SetValue)>
        {
            { "foo=", (new Func<Thing, string>((thing) => thing.Foo), new Action<Thing, string>((thing, value) => thing.Foo = value)) },
            { "bar=", (new Func<Thing, string>((thing) => thing.Bar), new Action<Thing, string>((thing, value) => thing.Bar = value)) },
        };

    public Thing Unstringify(string str)
    {
        Thing thing = new Thing();

        var split = str.Split('~');

        thing.Id = split.First();

        foreach (var keyValuePair in split.Skip(1))
        {
            var key = keyValuePair.Substring(0, 4);
            var value = keyValuePair.Substring(4);
            dictionary[key].SetValue(thing, value);
        }

        return thing;
    }

    public string Stringify(Thing thing)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(thing.Id);

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            var value = item.Value.GetValue(thing);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(item.Key);
                stringBuilder.Append(value);
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

It just seems very inelegant to have to specify a property in two different ways like this, and we end up with a lot of repeated code in those two dictionary entries. Reflection could be used to make this less messy possibly? But again, it feels like it shouldn't have to be to me. Something like this:

```
{ "foo=", Property<Thing>((thing) => thing.Foo) },
{ "bar=", Property<Thing>((thing) => thing.Bar) },
```

would be so much neater. Is there anything I can do with attributes (staying away from reflection) that might help in this instance?

Additionally, am I coming at this completely wrong? Is there a way of turning it on its head that makes handling the connection between a string and a property really succinct and neat? I seem to be encountering the need to relate strings to properties like this reasonably often at the moment, (or pass around a pointer to the property itself) and any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: We'd probably have to know the use case to see if you're coming at it completely wrong but at face value it's pretty hard to see a benefit of over complicating setting some string props.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - just to clarify, do you mean over complicating within or outside of the confines of the example? (I guess what i mean is, is there a stupidly easy way of doing this that I'm missing, apart from reflection?)

Comment: Serializing/deserializing using XML or JSON wouldn't fit your needs? There are many tools that have been extensively tested and are ready to use.

Comment: @JohnDarvill, based on your newest question, you seem to be dealing with common serialization problem.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This question is the OP's attempt to clarify his original question here:
[Is there a way to store a pointer to a property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993294/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-pointer-to-a-property-in-c)

The OP originally said that he is running into a need to do this quite regularly, which suggests he may be approaching the problem incorrectly. Looking at his new question above, it appears to be a serialization problem.

OP should go read everything he can about serialization and then see if he can put together an off the shelf solution.  Other responders have suggested use of Newtonsoft JSON, which I also think may be an appropriate solution for the OP.  Newtonsoft is known to be extremely fast, which makes it work on almost any situation. It's also pretty robust.

The only reason I would suggest NOT using Json serialization is if the OP needs his own more human-readable format.  And even if that's his need, there are still some off-the-shelf ways of achieving that.  Again, OP should read everything he can about serialization before proceeding.

Comment: To clarify, "Json serialization" is just one type of serialization.  Serialization is the process of turning an object into serial data (such as a string or byte array).  Deserialization is the reverse of that.

Answer (score 0):

For just the one `Thing` type, one pattern is for the stringify methods to be members of the original class:

```
class Thing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public static Thing FromString(string input)
    {
        var result = new Thing();
        var split = input.Split('~');

        result.Id = split[0];

        foreach (var keyValuePair in split.Skip(1))
        {
            var key = keyValuePair.Substring(0, 3).ToLower();

            if (key == "foo")
                result.Foo = keyValuePair.Substring(4);
            if (key == "bar")
                result.Bar = keyValuePair.Substring(4); 
        }

        return result;
    }

    public overrides string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}~foo={Foo}~bar={Bar}";
    }
}
```

Choosing to override the `ToString()` method can be especially nice, but you might also instead use paired static *Builder* or *Factory* classes if you need to handle several different formats, where the method or type names can indicate context.

However, using a dictionary seems like an attempt for make this work for any random type (or several specific types) with unknown or various properties. In this situation, where you want more reproducible and generic implementations, you may want to read up more on [**serialization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/). The link is just for the built-in stuff including in .Net. There are a number of additional libraries you can use to handle this kind of thing, as well.

Comment: I would go the serialization way. A single `~` character in any of the property values would break the code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the purpose of the code, as other have stated I would rather use Standard JSON serialization using Newtonsoft JSON for instance.

Regarding the property part of your question, there is no possibility to simply define a pointer to a property to avoid code duplication.

One thing though: you can use nameof() on a property like

```
class X
{
    bool Y {get;set;}
    void string foo() => nameof(Y);
}

new X().foo(); // return "Y"
```

In another stackoverflow question I proposed a way to create property pointers but that was more a proof of concept rather than a really usable thing: [PropertyPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993294/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-pointer-to-a-property-in-c/56993685#56993685)